# add track to a playlist spotify api web

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, spotify

I tried to add a track to a collaborative playlist, this is my code for the access token

```
$credentials = 'client_id:client_secret';

$headers = array(
           'Accept: */*',
           'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'User-Agent: runscope/0.1',
           'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($credentials));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
echo $token = $response['access_token'];
curl_close($ch);
```

in my page the user is not logged so I created the collaborative playlist

and this is my `add playlist` function

```
var addplaylist = function (id,token) {

      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/entelperú/playlists/6sU8XOS7BLicR3COsc0Rhp/tracks?uris=spotify:track:'+ id,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+token,
        },success: function (response) {
          alert(response);
        }
    });
  };
```

but it returns this

> {
>     "error" : {
>       "status" : 403,
>       "message" : "This request requires user authentication."
>     }
>   }

I don't know what happened, I've created the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { "error" : { "status" : 403, "message" : "This request requires user
>   authentication." } }

The request that you're making, to [Add a Track to a Playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/), requires an access token that's connected to a user.

The access tokens you're using can come from three different oAuth 2.0 flow. One of those flows, the Client Credentials flow, returns anonymous access tokens. Or rather, access tokens that are simply not connected to any user. Read more about the flows in the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

For some endpoints it's fine to use anonymous access tokens. Like retrieving playlists. But a lot of actions, like adding tracks, following artists, and saving tracks, requires a user to have given your application explicit permission to act on their behalf. This permission is also called [Scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/).

Therefore, what you need is to use a different oAuth 2.0 flow than the one you're using now. Which one depends on what type of application you're building. The important thing is that you need a user to approve the action that your application is performing.

Comment: Michael but in mi app the user not loggin so never get token for user, the playlist is mine i need, how can add the track?

Comment: Well, you need an access token that's connected to a user. That user can be your own. You can store the access token somewhere in your service and use it when needed. It does sound like you want to look at the Authorization Code flow since you may need a refresh token though. Please read the Authorization Guide on the Developer site, the answers you need is there.